# Binding DataContext on Boolean condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a UserControl that needs to be bind with two DataContext on the basis of a checkbox.

This UserControl have to display the data about the application (global) or selected DataGridRow.

```
class Person
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

UserControl has only two text fields to display name and Age. If "Global" checkbox is checked, then I want to bind this usercontrol with the property of `APerson` (of Person class) in MainViewModel and if it is unchecked then I have to bind the UserControl with the `SelectedItem` in `DataGrid`. SelectedItem is also a `Person` type

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could just play with your ViewModel to get what you want. Here is one way to do it.

You would be binding the `Checkbox.IsChecked` to 'IsGlobal' property in the ViewModel.
Then you would be binding the userControl to another property, say `SomePerson` in the ViewModel.
Lastly, in the `setter` of `IsGlobal` you would change the `SomePerson` to either `APerson` or  `SelectedItem` in your datagrid depending on the boolean state of `IsGlobal`.

Comment: It can be. But you will have to add duplicate user control in the view and bind their visibility to IsGlobal, and then use boolToVisibility converter to show only the required one..

Answer (score 0):

[Adding this here since you want a way to do it purely in XAML. I think that insisting on pure XAML here is not essential and @bit's answer is the right way to go, IMO.]

You can use style to have triggers that do the change.

Let's say your UC is called `MyUC` and currently you have an instance of it similar to: `<local:MyUC/>` in some other view/UC/window. You can change the instance to look like so:

```
<local:MyUC>
    <local:MyUC.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUC}">
            <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyDataGrid}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckbox, Path=IsChecked}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding APerson}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:MyUC.Style>
</local:MyUC>
```

I'm changing here the data context property, but you can change any other dependency property on `MyUC`.

Again, I think this is a less favorite approach to tackle this functionality, but it's pure XAML.